# How to add condition based on logged in user in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I need some help to show specific content for specific user. Expecting something similar to below

```
if( is_username('john')
{
  $echo 'Welcome john. You are from india.';
} else {
  $echo 'You have no rights to access this page...';
}
```

it should check condition only by username (text) not by user_id or any integer. Possible??

Comment: Use [get_currentuserinfo()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo) then compare `$current_user->user_login` with the username you want to check for.

Comment: i found this from there and it works :) '<?php if ($current_user->user_login == 'the_username') { ?>
<!-- Welcome the user or show the page content -->
<h1>Welcome <?php echo $current_user->user_firstname ?></h1>
<?php } else { ?>
<!-- Let the visitor know access is denied -->
<h1>Go away!</h1>
<?php } ?>'

Comment: great I added as full answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [get_currentuserinfo()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo) then compare `$current_user->user_login` with the username you want to check for.

for example:

```
get_currentuserinfo()
if($current_user->user_login == 'the_username') {
    echo 'woop';
} else {
    echo 'nope';
}
```